# ListBox with List<String> items

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to create a ListBox containing items of string type List in MVC Razor 5.

I have used SelectList for DropDownList, but this seems not to work.

How can I print a whole  List into ListBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better if you can show what you have tried.

If you have a `List<String>` you can simply create a `SelectList` by passing it to `SelectList` as below.

```
List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
// fill stringList
SelectList selectList = new SelectList(stringList);
```

Then in your view you can use that `SelectList` inside `DropDownList` helper as below.

```
@Html.DropDownList("yourlistname", selectList)
```